# scala: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error

Tags: scala, inferred-type

```
    val postFutureOption = postDAO.find(postId)
    val tagFutureOption = tagDAO.find(tagId)
    val tupleFutures = for{
      postOption <- postFutureOption
      tagOption <- tagFutureOption
    }yield(postOption, tagOption)

    tupleFutures.flatMap{tuple =>
      tuple match{
        case (Some(post),Some(tag)) => {
          def addPostTag(post: Post, tag: models.Tag): Future[Option[Post]] = {
            if(post.tags.map(_.tagId).contains(tagId)){
              Future.successful(Some(post))
            }else {
              postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId).map{_ => Some(post.copy(tags = post.tags :+ tag))}
            }
          }
          addPostTag(post, tag)
        }
        case _ => Future.successful(None)
      }
    }
  }
```

This code has fatal warning

```
a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.

    [error]           def addPostTag(post: Post, tag: models.Tag): Future[Option[Post]] = {
    [error]               ^
```

I don't really get what is the issue about: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9211
So please, advice if I can fix my code, or I need a workaround for the scala issue?

=====================

More  experiments:

```
tuple match{
        case (Some(post), Some(tag)) => {
          Future.successful(Some(post))
        }
        case _ => Future.successful(None)
      }
```

Compiles OK, but

```
tuple match{
        case (Some(post), Some(tag)) => {
          if(post.tags.map(_.tagId).contains(tagId)){
            Future.successful(Some(post))
          }else {
            postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId).map{_ => Some(post.copy(tags = post.tags :+ tag))}
          }
          Future.successful(Some(post))
        }
        case _ => Future.successful(None)
      }
```

Has the warning....

```
[error]         case (Some(post), Some(tag)) => {
[error]                                         ^
```

Comment: Your `addPostTag()` consists of a single `if` `else` statement.  Does the `else` return exactly the same type as the `if`?  If not the compiler will infer the method returns `Any`.

Comment: well, it can be compiled as                       `if(post.tags.map(_.tagId).contains(tagId)){
              val res: Future[Option[Post]] = Future.successful(Some(post))
              res
            }else {
              val res: Future[Option[Post]] = postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId).map{_ => Some(post.copy(tags = post.tags :+ tag))}
              res
            }`

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this problem, I think you have the `-Xlint` and `-Xfatal-warnings` compiler flags enabled. If you are desperate to get your code compiling immediately, you can disable these temporarily.

The error that you are getting indicates that the compiler inferred the type of this expression

```
if (post.tags.map(_.tagId).contains(tagId)){
  Future.successful(Some(post))
} else {
  postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId).map{_ => Some(post.copy(tags = post.tags :+ tag))}
}
```

to be `Any`. The problem is likely in the else branch of the code. I suggest assigning the expression to a variable with a declared type and verifying the type checks out. You can start with

```
val result: ExpectedType = postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId).map{_ => Some(post.copy(tags = post.tags :+ tag))}
result
```

It may also help to break down the expression into smaller chunks to insure the intermediate types are correct.

Comment: thanks, but this is done and commented to the post. No luck :(

Comment: Could you indicate what the compiler-inferred types of the intermediate expressions in your else branch? (i.e. `postDAO`, `postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId)` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

got it fixed as

```
case (Some(post), Some(tag)) => {
          if(post.tags.map(_.tagId.get).contains(tagId)){
            Future.successful(Some(post))
          }else {
            postDAO.addTag(postId, tagId).map{_ => Some(post.copy(tags = post.tags :+ tag))}
          }
        }
```

post.tags.map(_.tagId **.get** ).contains(tagId) as _.tagId is Option[Int] and tagId is just Int.

The compiler's message was really confusing, sorry about that...

Comment: Calling `get` on an `Option` should be discouraged, as it throws a `NoSuchElementException` when the `Option` is `None`. To be safe, you could consider pattern-matching, calling `isDefined` first or using `getOrElse` instead.